# overloaded method call ambiguity with ternary operator

Tags: java, definition, overloading

I am creating a simple wrapper class for numbers. Simply put, I want it to display the value `42` verses `42.0`; however, it should display the value `1.6180338` as that number. Simply enough.

### Code

```
private double number;

...

@Override
public String toString() {

    return String.valueOf(
            number == longValue()
                    ? longValue()
                    : number );

}

...

@Override 
public long longValue() { 

    return (long) number; 

}
```

### Issue

The problem is that the value of `42.0` is always displayed **Not** the correct `42` value in the `toString(...)` method

### My Thoughts

Although the `String.valueOf(...)` method has a lot of overloaded methods to display the correct primitive values as strings, there is ambiguity in which overloaded method to use. It can use `String.valueOf(double)` or `String.valueOf(long)`. This is because of the **ternary operator** statement and resulting result type.

I thought that the compiler would be able to discern the `long` type and call the appropriate `String.valueOf(long)` method. That appears to not be the case; instead, the JVM will choose at **compile time** the safest, yet most-confined overloaded method. In this case, that is `String.valueOf(double)` because it can safely convert a `long` to a `double`.

### Question

I know this isn't possible in Java right now, but is something like this available in other languages currently? And is there some kind of **definition** that explains this method, and can you explain it in more detail?

I mean a definition like `Covariance` or `Contra-variance`. Note: I realize that the definition is not one of those two :)

Comment: There is no special term for this. It's just that - at least in statically typed languages - every expression has one (output) *type*. (So the ternary operator expression has two input types, but only one output type) While the type could depend on the *type* of the input (in the case of generics, for example), it cannot depend on the *value* of the input. Non-statically typed languages (scripting languages, mostly) don't necessarily have this restriction, but then again they typically don't have overloading based on type either - as they usually don't have declared types, only actual types.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt "It cannot depend on the value of the input" Is this by value or by type? the expression `longValue()` has a `long` type where as `number` has a `double` type

Comment: It only has one output type, although it has two input types. The two input types are combined using the rules specified in the JLS section 15.25 as @TagirValeev has nicely referenced in his answer.

Comment: downvote? No research? not clear? not useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Java is statically typed language, the result of the ternary operator must have an explicit type, defined during the compilation, so the compilator can continue handling the outer expression. As the both branches of ternary are numbers, they are promoted to the more precise type as described in JLS [15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) and [5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). You can work-around this casting the arguments to the object:

```
return String.valueOf(
        number == longValue()
                ? (Object)longValue()
                : (Object)number );
```

This way you will box the numbers and use `String.valueOf(Object)` which works nice for both branches.

Comment: OK, took some time to understand, but finally got it. Thanks

Comment: However, I will move the `String.valueOf` inside the ternary operator ; in both the true and false parts as the cast seems kind of wrong